# Finding $\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{e^x\,dx}{1\:+\:e^{4x}}$ with residue integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

This integral was given as part of an exam in complex analysis. Here we are first asked to take the contour integral of the rectangle below.

[image: task and contour of integration]

This is computed by finding the poles:

$$z\:=\:\frac{1}{4}\left(i\pi \:+\:i2\pi c_1\right),\:c_1\in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Only $iπ/4$ and $i3π/4$ are inside the contour and we proceed to find the solution of the contour integral:

$$\frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{2}$$

This is fine, however, when asked to compute the real integral (task **c)** in the linked picture), I struggle to understand how we rigorously can be sure that

$$ \frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{4}$$

is the correct answer. This leads to my question:

**Q.** Could I reach the same result by instead using the "standard" semicircle in the upper half-plane, and let the radius $R$ approach infinity. Or is this an integral where I need to choose a different geometric contour to reach the correct answer? If so, how do I proceed to find the correct contour in a similar situation where I am not given the shape beforehand?

[image: semicircle in the upper half-plane]

I am puzzled because the integral has four poles in the unit circle, but if we instead look at the imaginary axis, it has an infinite number of poles when the radius approaches infinity.

Comment: The essential point here is that the integral along the real axis _isn't_ the only relevant piece of the puzzle. The integral along the 'top edge' of the rectangle also goes to a non-zero value as your limits go to infinity; that needs to be related back to the real integral.

Comment: Yes, that I understand, however, is that the main method of solving this integral or could I use the semi-circle?

Comment: If you were to use a semi-circle then you would (atleast) want $e^z/(1+e^{4z})$ to go to zero as $R\to \infty$. Is this the case? What is the value close to the imaginary axis $z \sim iR$ ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is impossible to use semicircular contour to compute the integral, but that will be far more complicated. If possible, I would very much stick to the rectangular contour in the first picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the substitution $e^x=t$, $e^xdx=dt$, the integral, considering the integrand is now an even function, becomes:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{1+t^4}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^4}\;.$$

Now

$$f(z)\equiv \frac{1}{1+z^4}$$

has four poles, only two of which fall inside the upper semicircle, namely $z_1=e^{πi/4}$ and $z_2=e^{3πi/4}$. Therefore, you only need to evaluate the residues of $f(z)$ at those two poles.
By differentiation you will quickly find that

$$Res(f,z_1)+Res(f,z_2)=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{z_1^3}+\frac{1}{z_2^3}\right)\;.$$

The integral on the upper semicircle can be easily shown to approach $0$ as $R\to \infty$, so if you put all the above results together and use the residue theorem you get the expected result of $\frac{π}{2\sqrt{2}}$.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Notice that to be able to use the upper semicircle contour method I had to change the integrand and work with $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^4}$. But the two methods are perfectly equivalent and take (me, at least) more or less the same time. This typology of integrals containing exponential and hyperbolic functions can usually be solved by either of these methods. There are some general patterns when it comes to solving real integrals by residue methods, but it's experience that suggests the approach to use. Again, this is my personal view on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The integral along the top horizontal side is

$$\int_M^{-M} \frac{e^{x+\pi i}}{1+e^{4(x+\pi i)}}dx=\int_{-M}^M\frac{e^x}{1+e^{4x}}dx$$

Therefore the result is exactly half of the contour integral.

It won't be easy to do it with the semi-circle contour. For one thing, it will enclose more and more singularities.

Comment: How would you proceed to solve this integral if you do not know which contour to use? Is there a method to deduce a contour that creates the simplest integral?